# GROUP BY getting the second highest date

Tags: t-sql

I'm currently doing this group by to retrieve the max date :

```
SELECT A, MAX(B) FROM X GROUP BY A
```

This is perfectly working. However, when I try to retrieve the second highest value, I'm totally lost.

If anyone has an idea...

Comment: Second highest for each group?

Comment: `MAX()` will return only literally the one single maximum value in the table. If you want 2nd-highest, you can't use it. You'll have to hack together something with `select top X` or use a partition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the ranking function `ROW_NUMBER` in a [cte](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx):

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT A, 
           MaxB = MAX(B)OVER(PARTITION BY A), 
           RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A ORDER By B DESC)
    FROM dbo.X 
)
SELECT A, MaxB
FROM CTE
WHERE RN <= 2
```

This will return the two highest values for each group (if that is what you want).

Comment: with B instead of "MaxB = MAX(B)OVER(PARTITION BY A)"

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT X.A,
MAX(X.B)
FROM YourTable X
JOIN 
(
    SELECT
        X1.A,
        MAX(X1.B)
    FROM YourTable X1
    GROUP BY X1.A
) X1 ON X1.A = X.A
    AND X.B < X1.B
GROUP BY X.A
```

Basically this says get the max of all the ones that are less than the max.

Answer (score 0):

You're columns are rather ambiguous, but if A is max_date then, B is some other value you wish to sort by, then one way to do it could be:

```
SELECT A FROM X ORDER BY B DESC LIMIT 2
```

Which will give you 2 rows with the second highest displayed first.